# Accidently removed localhost.crt SSL in Centos 6 - what can i do?

Tags: centos, ssl, ssl-certificate, centos6

So I just got my certificate issued from Digicert, and since there was other unused/old files in /etc/ssl/ i marked and removed, and accidently also removed localhost.crt.

Now I cannot start my web server (only without SSL). How do i recreate this localhost.crt file? And would i need to make a new key and get my certificate from digicert reissued?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes the certificate i want running is not self signed, its by digicert. But /etc/ssl/certs/ only contains the certificate from digicert and csr i genereated for it. But in order to start my webserver it requires localhost.csr which i removed?

Comment: Restore it from your backup.

Comment: I dont have backup

Comment: Then the most important thing you can do today is put a backup system in place.

Comment: This file (localhost.crt) is generated with the script `/etc/pki/tls/certs/make-dummy-cert` on Red Hat, CentOS, and derivatives. You should not need it after you configure your web server to use the DigiCert certificate, but I wanted to add this to the conversation.

Comment: Frickin' hell. My localhost.crt file is not there, and it's preventing me from getting a certificate (apachectl configtest exits with an error). I hate that this question was downvoted. There are more than one way that a file can be lost, and one of those ways may involve a brand new machine that's still being built (and not *yet* backed up). This is a perfectly valid- and useful- question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your ssl certificate issuer should provide you free replacement or reissue. Just go to digicert and ask them.

Generate new key files from server and reissue ssl. Make sure the new ssl should be SHA2 only.

Answer (score 10):

There are two solutions to this issue:

**1) You can regenerate the default self-signed certificate using OpenSSL:**

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/localhost.crt
```

**2) You can search the Apache config files and replace the self-signed cert with the new certificate.**

This command will tell you which Apache config files reference the localhost.crt file:

```
grep -i -r localhost.crt /etc/httpd/
```

An example output of the above command might be this:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
```

That tells us to look in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf and update the SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile, and SSLCertificateChainFile to their new DigiCert certificate files.

---

Please feel free to call DigiCert support at 1-801-701-9600 if you have any problems or questions.

Answer (score 4):

The files `/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt` and `/etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key` are created by the postinstall script of the `mod_ssl` package. You can find the CentOS 7 spec file here: https://git.centos.org/rpms/httpd/blob/c7/f/SPECS/httpd.spec (check the other branches for different CentOS versions). Here is the script from CentOS 7:

```
%define sslcert %{_sysconfdir}/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
%define sslkey %{_sysconfdir}/pki/tls/private/localhost.key

%post -n mod_ssl
umask 077

if [ -f %{sslkey} -o -f %{sslcert} ]; then
   exit 0
fi

%{_bindir}/openssl genrsa -rand /proc/apm:/proc/cpuinfo:/proc/dma:/proc/filesystems:/proc/interrupts:/proc/ioports:/proc/pci:/proc/rtc:/proc/uptime 2048 > %{sslkey} 2> /dev/null

FQDN=`hostname`
if [ "x${FQDN}" = "x" -o ${#FQDN} -gt 59 ]; then
   FQDN=localhost.localdomain
fi

cat << EOF | %{_bindir}/openssl req -new -key %{sslkey} \
         -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -set_serial $RANDOM -extensions v3_req \
         -out %{sslcert} 2>/dev/null
--
SomeState
SomeCity
SomeOrganization
SomeOrganizationalUnit
${FQDN}
root@${FQDN}
EOF
```

So if you delete both `localhost.key` and `localhost.crt`, and do `yum reinstall mod_ssl`, then the postinstall script will recreate them for you.

(I'm posting this answer because searching how to recreate `/etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt` leads me here, but as others stated, if you got a cert signed by a CA, you don't need the `localhost.crt` and `localhost.key` files any more.)

Comment: I tried the reinstall on Fedora 27 but it did not create the package.

Comment: I had to create my own private key, as per https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Comment: Upvoted because it got me to understand how to create the keys on my system, even if I needed to type in a different series of commands.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem. There was no default localhost certificate for CentOS 8 so I ran this and it regenerated all the default certs.

```
/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-gencerts
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reinstall ssl with following command.It will regenerate localhost.crt

yum -y install mod_ssl

Comment: sorry its yum -y reinstall mod_ssl

Comment: The answer you have posted doesn't address the question. The question is looking to recover a certificate file issued by digicert that has been accidentlly deleted.